# How can I implement async requests without 3rd party packages in Python 2.7

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-requests

What I want is in title. The backgroud is I have thousands of requests to send to a very slow Restful interface in the program where all 3rd party packages are **not** allowed to imported into, except *requests*.

The speed of **MULTITHREADING** AND **MULTIPROCESSING** is limited to GIL and the 4 cores computer in which the program will be run.

I know you can implement an incomplete coroutine in Python 2.7 by generator and yield key word, but how can I make it possible to do thousands of requests with the incomplete coroutine ability?

#### Example

```
url_list = ["https://www.example.com/rest?id={}".format(num) for num in range(10000)]
results = request_all(url_list) # do asynchronously
```

Comment: Good luck with your work test

Comment: The speed of multiprocessing is not limited by the GIL. The speed of multithreading is only limited by the GIL for CPU-bound code, which yours is not. So, your entire premise is wrong from the start.

Comment: @abarnert to be clearer, multiprocessing is limited by how many cores you have, and if you raise 10 threads to send requests, the 5th one will be blocked if you only have 4 cores, that what I mean here.

Comment: @Spike No, that's just wrong. If you have 4 cores and 100 processes, and 98 of those processes are blocked on a `socket.recv`, the other 2 run just fine. If you've got 20 processes all trying to do CPU-bound work, then of course they have to share the 4 cores—but if you're using async instead of multiprocessing, they all have to share _1_ core, so it's 4 times as bad.

Comment: And likewise, with threads, the 5th one will not be blocked unless they're all doing CPU-bound work. And, again, if they _are_ doing CPU-bound work, async will be even worse than threads, not better. (But multiprocessing will be much better than either.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're starting from an incorrect premise.

- The speed of multiprocessing is not limited by the GIL at all.
- The speed of multiprocessing is only limited by the number of cores for CPU-bound work, which yours is not. And async doesn't work at all for CPU-bound work, so multiprocessing would be 4x better than async, not worse.
- The speed of multithreading is only limited by the GIL for CPU-bound code, which, again, yours is not.
- The speed of multithreading is barely affected by the number of cores. If your code is CPU-bound, the threads mostly end up serialized on a single core. But again, async is even worse here, not better.

The reason people use `async` is that not that it solves any of these problems; in fact, it only makes them worse. The main advantage is that if you have a ton of workers that are doing almost no work, you can schedule a ton of waiting-around coroutines more cheaply than a ton of waiting-around threads or processes. The secondary advantage is that you can tie the selector loop to the scheduler loop and eliminate a bit of overhead coordinating them.

---

Second, you can't use `requests` with `asyncio` in the first place. It expects to be able to block the whole thread on socket reads. There was a project to rewrite it around an `asyncio`-based transport adapter, but it was abandoned unfinished.

The usual way around that is to use it in threads, e.g., with `run_in_executor`. But if the only thing you're doing is `requests`, building an event loop just to dispatch things to a thread pool executor is silly; just use the executor directly.

---

Third, I doubt you actually need to have thousands of requests running in parallel. Although of course the details depend on your service or your network or whatever the bottleneck is, it's almost always more efficient to have a thread pool that can run, say, 12 or 64 requests running in parallel, with the other thousands queued up behind them.

Handling thousands of concurrent connections (and therefore workers) is usually something you only have to do on a server. Occasionally you have to do it on a client that's aggregating data from a huge number of different services. But if you're just hitting a single service, there's almost never any benefit to that much concurrency.

---

Fourth, if you really do want a coroutine-based event loop in Python 2, by far the easiest way is to use `gevent` or `greenlets` or another such library.

Yes, they give you an event loop hidden under the covers where you can't see it, and "magic" coroutines where the yielding happens inside methods like `socket.send` and `Thread.join` instead of being explicitly visible with `await` or `yield from`, but the plus side is that they already work—and, in fact, the magic means they work with `requests`, which anything you build  will not.

Of course you don't want to use any third-party libraries. Building something just like `greenlets` yourself on top of Stackless or PyPy is pretty easy; building it for CPython is a lot more work. And then you still have to do all the monkeypatching that `gevent` does to make libraries like `sockets` work like magic, or rewrite `requests` around explicit greenlets.

---

Anyway, if you really want to build an event loop on top of just plain `yield`, you can.

In [Greg Ewing's original papers on why Python needed to add `yield from`](http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/greg.ewing/python/yield-from/), he included examples of a coroutine event loop with just `yield`, and a better one that uses an explicit trampoline to `yield` to—with a simple networking-driven example. He even wrote an automatic translator from code for the (at the time not implemented) `yield from` to Python 3.1.

Notice that having to bounce every yield off a trampoline makes things a lot less efficient. There's really no way around that. That's a good part of the reason we have `yield from` in the language.

But that's just the scheduler part with a bit of toy networking. You still need to integrate a `selectors` loop and then write coroutines to replace all of the `socket` functions you need. Consider how long `asyncio` took Guido to build when he knew Python inside and out and had `yield from` to work with… but then you can steal most of his design, so it won't be quite *that* bad. Still, it's going to be a lot of work.

(Oh, and you don't have `selectors` in Python 2. If you don't care about Windows, it's pretty easy to build the part you need out of the `select` module, but if you *do* care about Windows, it's a lot more work.)

And remember, because `requests` won't work with your code, you're also going to need to reimplement most of *it* as well. Or, maybe better, port `aiohttp` from `asyncio` to your framework.

And, in the end, I'd be willing to give you odds that the result is not going to be anywhere near as efficient as `aiohttp` in Python 3, or `requests` on top of `gevent` in Python 2, or just `requests` on top of a thread pool in either.

And, of course, you'll be the only person in the world using it. `asyncio` had hundreds of bugs to fix between `tulip` and going into the stdlib, which were only detected because dozens of early adopters (including people who are serious experts on this kind of thing) were hammering on it. And `requests`, `aiohttp`, `gevent`, etc. are all used by thousands of servers handling zillions of dollars worth of business, so you benefit from all of those people finding bugs and needing fixes. Whatever you build almost certainly won't be nearly as reliable as any of those solutions.

All this for something you're probably going to need to port to Python 3 anyway, since Python 2 hits end-of-life in less than a year and a half, and distros and third-party libraries are already disengaging from it. For a relevant example, `requests` 3.0 is going to require at least Python 3.5; if you want to stick with Python 2.7, you'll be stuck with `requests` 2.1 forever.

Comment: thanks for your great answer! It seems that I mistook a lot of basics here. I think the best solution here is requests with thread pool, right? Of course as you mentioned above, it's better to use some mature, proved packages rather than doing it by myself, but how things go in my company: using opensource software needs verification whose process is quite comlicated. And, the version in our clients is always old Python 2.7.

Comment: @Spike Yes, `requests` with a thread pool (probably the one in [`multiprocessing.dummy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy)) is probably a good answer. But you might want to try with, say, `gevent`, and benchmark it both ways. If a thread pool is better, or almost as good, then great—you know you made the right choice. If `gevent` turns out to be a whole lot better… well, at least then you have some ammunition to explain to your manager why they should push for it to be approved.